# Did Vice Admiral Holdo know about Rey's mission?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-last-jedi

I was recently rewatching *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*. In one scene, Rey mentions to BB-8 that she still can't get through to the resistance.

At this point in the film Vice Admiral Holdo has also taken over General Leia's resistance role, for which Poe Dameron is scheming behind her back, believing her to be nefarious or dangerous to the resistance's plight.

With that being said, my question is, *Did Holdo even know about Rey and the mission she's on to bring Luke Skywalker into the fold? Does any of the tie-in material shed light on her perspective?*

Answer (score 4):

> Did Holdo even know about Rey and the mission she's on to bring Luke Skywalker into the fold? Does any of the tie-in material shed light on her perspective?

Since a large majority of the *The Force Awakens* entailed Leia and The Resistance completing the map that led to Luke to then recruit him for help, I would strongly think that Holdo (though there's never any mentioning of it in *The Last Jedi*, AFAIK) was completely aware of Rey and her actions.

However, since that plan was such a long shot *and* given the nature of Holdo, there'd be no reason for her to base her strategies off such a hope (though that *is* a prevailing concept throughout the film).

If you even just consider Dameron's plan to deactivate the lead star destroyer's hyperspace tracker and how Holdo reacted to that --

> HOLDO: You have bet the survival of the Resistance on bad odds and put us all at risk? There's no time now. We have to get clear of the cruiser. Load the transports.

-- knowing about Rey's attempt to recruit Luke wouldn't have changed Holdo's decisions/actions.